# Preload a script in react-native-webview

Tags: react-native-webview

I am using react-native-webview so i want to load script in this. So as the webview calls it loads my script and show my content everytime.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View } from 'react-native';
import { WebView } from 'react-native-webview';

// ...
class MyWebComponent extends Component {
  render() {
    return <WebView source={{ uri: 'https://reactnative.dev/' }} />;
  }
}
```

So i want to that i will load a Script in the package react-native-webview so that it will load script once and then show my content according to that. So let me know in which file i can make changes in the package to load some script intially.